# Is it exist such tool that can log cpu percentage in windows

Tags: logging, cpu

I know with the help of windows Task Manager or Pmon.exe we can see the real time cpu percentage and other resource occupation, but I want to log these information into files with intervals,any recommendations or suggestions will be very appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do significant monitoring, get the real thing (IMO) - Nagios

http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Distributions/Nagios-Core-32bit-Windows-Installer/details

Add Centreon on top of it and you have a beautiful console, graphing capabilities, notifications, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your recommendation,but the Nagios-Core-32bit can only support the 32bit OS,sometimes I also need to monitor on Win7 64bit,so finally I write a tiny programe to achieve my requirement,the python code with WMI support

```
#!/usr/bin/python #
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging
import logging.handlers
import wmi
import time
import ConfigParser
class CpuMonitor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        cf = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        cf.read("config.ini")
        if cf.has_option("mointor", "interval"):
            self._interval = cf.get("mointor", "interval")
        else:
            self._interval = 5
        if cf.has_option("mointor", "logfile"):
            self._logfile = cf.get("mointor", "logfile")
        else:
            self._logfile = "stdout.log"
    def monitor_cpu(self):
        c = wmi.WMI()
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        hdlr =   logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(self._logfile,maxBytes=102400000,backupCount=3)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
        hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(hdlr)
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        while True:
            for cpu in c.Win32_Processor():
                logger.info('Utilization: %s: %d %%' % (cpu.DeviceID, cpu.LoadPercentage))
                time.sleep(self._interval)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    w = CpuMonitor()
    w.monitor_cpu()
```